# Load data in Laravel from array

Tags: laravel

Hello does it exist any analogue of the method load from yii2 which loads all data from the array or request into the model in laravel ?
that is, I receive a request, check the validation, create a model and load data from the request into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instance of the class that is the model you're trying to create passing your request as the constructor parameter.
However, only the properties in the `protected $fillable` variable in the model will populate the model.
If the model already exists (say in an update), you can use the `->fill()` method with the same effect.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#mass-assignment